# Mapping the Microsoft Graph response to Java POJO - API returned value do not match MSGraph Models Enum values

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to map the response from the MSGraph API call to retrieve a list of email messages.
I'm using jackson fasterxml and mapping into the API provided classes - MessageCollectionResponse which contains a list of Message pojos

However, the Message class itself has four enums that will not map because the values returned from the API are lowercase, and the ENUM values are only UPPERCASE
(and in one instance (flagStatus) spelled differently).

The API's reponse that won't map are key/value pairs - "importance":"normal", "contentType":"html", "flagStatus": "notFlagged", "inferenceClassification":"focused"
which appear to correspond to package com.microsoft.graph.models enum classes Importance.class, , ItemBody.class/BodyType.class, FollowupFlag.class, InferenceClassificationType.class

**My code...**

```
        String userPrincipleName = URLEncoder.encode("myemailaddress@domain.com", 
           java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());  
        URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + userPrincipleName + 
           "/messages");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Request","application/json");           
        int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(httpResponseCode == HTTPResponse.SC_OK) {                
            StringBuilder response;             
               try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))){
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuilder();
                    while (( inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    } 
                } 
        String responseString = response.toString(); 
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new 
           ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();  
        MessageCollectionResponse responseX = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, 
           MessageCollectionResponse.class);
```

**Here's the exception...**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type
 `com.microsoft.graph.models.Importance` from String "normal": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [HIGH, UNEXPECTED_VALUE, LOW, NORMAL]
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 750] (through reference chain: 
 com.microsoft.graph.requests.MessageCollectionResponse["value"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.microsoft.graph.models.Message["importance"])
```

**Here's the field on the API Message model for example...**

```
 /**
     * The Importance.
     * The importance of the message. The possible values are: low, normal, and high.
     */
    @SerializedName(value = "importance", alternate = {"Importance"})
    @Expose
    @Nullable
    public Importance importance;

**Here's the API Emum class for example..**
// Template Source: Enum.java.tt
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the MIT License.  See License in the project root for license information.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.microsoft.graph.models;


/**
 * The Enum Importance.
*/
public enum Importance
{
    /**
    * low
    */
    LOW,
    /**
    * normal
    */
    NORMAL,
    /**
    * high
    */
    HIGH,
    /**
    * For Importance values that were not expected from the service
    */
    UNEXPECTED_VALUE
}
```

I could use Jackson to ignore these fields from mapping, but thought maybe others might have experienced this.  Reviewing the Microsoft Graph models from version to version, I don't see that
these ENUMS ever changed, they appear to always be UPPERCASE.  So, maybe there is a better way to map the response that I'm just not seeing or finding in the Microsoft Documentation. I'm using version 3.9.0 of microsoft-graph.

Comment: Does the issue happens only with SDK? You may want to isolate the issue by testing the respective API call in Graph explorer or postman.

Comment: The graph explorer returns the data the same way - lowercase or spelled incorrectly as compared to their provided entity models. 

I haven’t been able to get their SDK provided GraphClient to work so I haven’t seen if it works differently, ie maps the data somehow to their classes correctly.  

At this point, I’m just using the $select feature to only pull back the fields I want and thus avoiding the issues. It’s not ideal but works.

Comment: great to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Graph deserializer

```
DefaultSerializer serializer = new DefaultSerializer(new DefaultLogger());
MessageCollectionResponse responseObject = serializer.deserializeObject(responseString, MessageCollectionResponse .class);
```

The Importance is an Enum and you have to use the Serializer from MS who handle it.